# starting new paragraph with \marginpar that is correctly aligned

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar

I am trying to define a command like `\introduce{...}` that among others will print its content into the margin.

I though "simple", just do `\newcommand{\introduce}[1]{\marginpar{#1}#1}`.

My reasoning to put `#1` after the `\marginpar{#1}` is to start the maringpar in the line of the first word, as otherwise it looks weird with longer things that only have their last word flow over to the next line.

I however noticed that when the first words of a paragraph are highlighted this way, the marginpar aligns with the previous line.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\introduce}[1]{\marginpar{#1}\emph{#1}} % too high
% \newcommand{\introduce}[1]{\emph{#1}\marginpar{#1}} % too low

\begin{document}

Bacon ipsum dolour sit amet porchetta beef turkey, bacon turducken boudin hamburger venison ball tip. Brisket pork loin bresaola short loin ground round leberkas pastrami tongue jerky cow turducken beef ribs. Pork ribeye landjaeger prosciutto pig venison tenderloin. Swine beef ribs kielbasa, porchetta tenderloin salami venison pork belly tail.

\introduce{More Bacon} ipsum dolour sit amet porchetta beef turkey, bacon turducken boudin hamburger venison ball tip. Brisket pork loin bresaola short loin ground round leberkas pastrami tongue jerky cow turducken beef ribs. Pork ribeye landjaeger prosciutto pig venison tenderloin. Swine beef ribs kielbasa, porchetta tenderloin salami venison pork belly tail.

Ipsum dolour sit amet porchetta beef turkey, bacon turducken boudin hamburger \introduce{even more Bacon} venison ball tip. Brisket pork loin bresaola short loin ground round leberkas pastrami tongue jerky cow turducken beef ribs. Pork ribeye landjaeger prosciutto pig venison tenderloin. Swine beef ribs kielbasa, porchetta tenderloin salami venison pork belly tail.

\end{document}
```

#### too high:

[image: too high]

#### too low:

[image: too low]

Comment: see my 2nd picture... it starts below the `even` aligning with `more Bacon`, but i'd like it to generally align with the first line of the highlighted words

Comment: off topic: the margin notes would look much nicer set ragged right.

Comment: yupp, just didn't want to complicate the MWE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `\leavevmode` so the paragraph will be started anyhow.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\introduce}[1]{%
  \leavevmode % if at the start of a paragraph 
  \marginpar{#1}% the note
  \emph{#1}% the text
}

\begin{document}

Bacon ipsum dolour sit amet porchetta beef turkey, bacon turducken 
boudin hamburger venison ball tip. Brisket pork loin bresaola short 
loin ground round leberkas pastrami tongue jerky cow turducken beef 
ribs. Pork ribeye landjaeger prosciutto pig venison tenderloin. 
Swine beef ribs kielbasa, porchetta tenderloin salami venison pork 
belly tail.

\introduce{More Bacon} ipsum dolour sit amet porchetta beef turkey, 
bacon turducken boudin hamburger venison ball tip. Brisket pork loin 
bresaola short loin ground round leberkas pastrami tongue jerky cow 
turducken beef ribs. Pork ribeye landjaeger prosciutto pig venison 
tenderloin. Swine beef ribs kielbasa, porchetta tenderloin salami 
venison pork belly tail.

Ipsum dolour sit amet porchetta beef turkey, bacon turducken boudin 
hamburger \introduce{even more Bacon} venison ball tip. Brisket pork 
loin bresaola short loin ground round leberkas pastrami tongue jerky 
cow turducken beef ribs. Pork ribeye landjaeger prosciutto pig venison 
tenderloin. Swine beef ribs kielbasa, porchetta tenderloin salami 
venison pork belly tail.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick answers, but which of them to accept, both work... any downside of this compared to david's answer?

Comment: @JörnHees my analysis was not persuasive it seems:(

Comment: I tried using your answer to add color to the margin text by `\marginpar{\color{red}#1}` with the `xcolor` package, and the margintext is then placed too low. Do you know what happens here and how to fix it?

Comment: @Simon The same: `\leavevmode` before `\color`

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\introduce}[1]{\mbox{}\marginpar{#1}\emph{#1}}

\begin{document}

Bacon ipsum dolour sit amet porchetta beef turkey, bacon turducken boudin hamburger venison ball tip. Brisket pork loin bresaola short loin ground round leberkas pastrami tongue jerky cow turducken beef ribs. Pork ribeye landjaeger prosciutto pig venison tenderloin. Swine beef ribs kielbasa, porchetta tenderloin salami venison pork belly tail.

\introduce{More Bacon} ipsum dolour sit amet porchetta beef turkey, bacon turducken boudin hamburger venison ball tip. Brisket pork loin bresaola short loin ground round leberkas pastrami tongue jerky cow turducken beef ribs. Pork ribeye landjaeger prosciutto pig venison tenderloin. Swine beef ribs kielbasa, porchetta tenderloin salami venison pork belly tail.

Ipsum dolour sit amet porchetta beef turkey, bacon turducken boudin hamburger \introduce{even more Bacon} venison ball tip. Brisket pork loin bresaola short loin ground round leberkas pastrami tongue jerky cow turducken beef ribs. Pork ribeye landjaeger prosciutto pig venison tenderloin. Swine beef ribs kielbasa, porchetta tenderloin salami venison pork belly tail.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick answers, but which of them to accept, both work... any downside of this compared to egreg's answer?

Comment: `mbox` is a documented latex command but just works here because internally it uses `\leavevmode` which is the command egreg used. But whenever there is a choice between giving a tick to egreg and not doing so, not doing so is always the right choice,:-)

Comment: oh-oh, no matter what i do now, i'm drawn into some battle here it seems :D good move ;) I'll however go with the answer that i think is less implicit, hope that won't cause a grudge.

Comment: This does not work for double-page layouts. With `mbox`, when the paragraph starts on a new line, the margin note will be placed on the wrong side of the page. Use the `leavevmode` solution.

Comment: @MichaelSchmid I don't see what you describe can possibly happen, are you sure you didn't use `\hbox` (which is `\mbox` without a `\leavevmode`

Comment: I am sure I used `mbox`. But of course it should be “when the paragraph starts on a new _page_” (it always starts on a new line).

Comment: @MichaelSchmid `\mbox{}\marginpar{wibble}one two..` is `\leavevmode\hbox{}\marginpar{wibble}one two..` and I can think of no cases where that produces a different output to `\leavevmode\marginpar{wibble}one two..` That doesn't mean that it can't happen, it just means I don't see how it can happen, feel free to post an answer with an example if you have one, I'd be interested to see it!

Comment: Just want to point out, that the `\mbox` approach doesn't cause a minuscule indentation of the paragraph in my case, as opposed to the `\leavevmode`. I don't know if its something I'm doing or not.